# AWS Quicksight - filter broker but show every other broker covering the same counties

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a quicksight dashboard with a pivot table that shows counties and the brokerages that have coverage in each county. I have leads sent to each brokerage and their market share compared to the rest of the brokerages covering the county. I am trying to set a filter for brokerage code where if I select one brokerage code the pivot table will return all the counties that the brokerage has coverage in as well as the competing brokerages in the same county. Is this possible? Would I have to set up a parameter looking to see if brokerages have coverage in a county?

ex. I filter for broker1 and they cover counties 1,2,3 and 4. I want to return all the brokerages that cover counties 1,2,3 and 4 in the pivot table so I can compare, instead of filtering for each county individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the filters to all the visuals. When you filter on a field, all the visuals will be updated accordingly.

In your case, you can put a filter on the Broker column(Broker1) and apply it to all visuals. Your pivot table for the countries will display the brokerages covering the 1,2,3 and 4 countries.

PS: If you want to put filters on dates you can set parameters and then set the filters with parameters. But for non numeric data I would suggest you can work with just filters